# In next.js where should i do the authentication?

Tags: authentication, jwt, next.js, token

I'm using next.js with redux toolkit. My back-end REST API is written with node.js and express with jwt tokens.

When the user signs up I have a lot of possibilities where can I implement the logic.

e.g.

```
getInitialProps()
getStaticProps
getServerSideProps
```

or I can do it neither of those with my own function and let next decide what to do.

What is the best practice? Where should I put the code for registration and login?

Comment: Maybe give this a look first: https://nextjs.org/docs/authentication and see the [examples](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples).